# How can I start docker.service after nslcd.service?

Tags: linux, docker, unix, service, systemctl

All my unix host use the ldap backend.

`docker` group is existing on the ldap, this is also why `docker.service` must start after `nslcd.service`.

I have tried to edit `systemctl` startup configuration for `docker.service`:

```
$ sudo systemctl edit --full docker.service
```

And I add `nslcd.service` to `After`, `Wants`, `Requires`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Docker Application Container Engine
Documentation=https://docs.docker.com
After=network-online.target docker.socket firewalld.service nslcd.service
Wants=network-online.target nslcd.service
Requires=docker.socket nslcd.service
```

I still can't get docker to run after that service:

```
sudo service docker status
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com

Oct 10 19:35:02 dev-08 systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Docker Application Container Engine.
```

There is no problem to start container manually after starts, since I login through ldap.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> docker group is existing on the ldap, this is also why docker.service must start after nslcd.service.

It is generally a bad idea to have system services depend on users and groups in a remote directory service (because problems with the directory service can impact service availability on your host).

> And I add nslcd.service to After, Wants, Requires

Specifying both a `Wants=` and a `Requires=` relationship is redundant.  The `Requires=` relationship is simply a stronger version of `Wants=`: using `Requires=` means that if you start the `docker` service, and `nslcd` is not already running, it will be started as well.  Using `Wants=` in the same situation, `docker` would start without starting `nslcd`.

> I still can't get docker to run after that service

Is is entirely likely that `nslcd` takes a moment to connect to the directory service. In this case, it's possible that the *process* has started, which satisfies the `After=` dependency, so `docker` starts even though your groups are not yet available.

There are a few ways of addressing this situation:

1. In light of my initial comment, just create a local `docker` group. This is by far the simplest and most robust solution.
2. Create a new oneshot unit that spins until the `docker` group exists.  Make *this* unit depend on `nslcd`, and make `docker` depend on the new unit.
3. Possibly replacing `nslcd` with something that implements local caching (e.g., [sssd](https://github.com/SSSD/sssd)) would also resolve this problem.

On a different note, it is a bad idea to directly edit the unit files as you have done in this example, because if you've installed Docker via packaging tools (apt/yum/etc), your modifications will be overwritten next time you upgrade the package.  A better solution is to create [drop-in files](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/systemd#Drop-in_files) to augment the unit configuration.

**Update**

Option 2 might look like this:

```
[Unit]
Requires=nslcd.service docker.service
After=nslcd.service
Before=docker.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "while ! getent group docker; do sleep 1; done"
```